# Proving that local base determines topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space and $\mathcal{B}$ a collection of neighborhoods of $0$ such that every neighborhood of $0$ contains a member of $\mathcal{B}$ (that is, $\mathcal{B}$ is a local base at $0$).

[Rudin](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Functional_Analysis.html?id=Sh_vAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) proves that $\tau$ is translation-invariant. It follows that the translate of any member of $\mathcal{B}$ is open and thus **any union of translates of members of $\mathcal{B}$ is open.**

Rudin also states the converse: if $U\subset X$ is open then $U$ is the union of translates of members of $\mathcal{B}$.

It's probably elementary, but I'd like help to justify this assertion.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you translate $U$ to zero, write it as a union of things in $\mathcal B$ and then translate everything back?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I understood your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is open then for each $x \in U$, $U - x = \{y - x | y \in U\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$ and hence contains some $V_x \in \mathcal{B}$. Then $x \in V_x + x \subset U$, so $U = \bigcup (V_x + x)$.

Answer (score -1):

On a topological space $X$, the collection of local bases at each point determines the topology because any open set is a union of sets from local bases. This of course continues to be true in topological vector spaces but the special thing in topological vector spaces is that if you have a local base at $0$, then by translating this base you get a local base at each point.

In summary, the local base at $0$ gives you a collection of local bases at each point by translations and this collection determines the whole topology.